# Aggregate function calls cannot be nested?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In `PostgreSQL` database I have table called `answers`. This table stores information about how users answered a questions. There are only 4 question in the table. At the same time, the number of users who answered the questions can be dynamic and the user can answer only part of the questions.

Table `answers`:

```
| EMPLOYEE | QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT          | OPTION_ID | OPTION_TEXT  |
|----------|-------------|------------------------|-----------|--------------|
| Bob      | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 1         | Yes          |
| Alex     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 2         | No           |
| Kate     | 1           | Do you like soup?      | 3         | I don't know |
| Bob      | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1         | Yes          |
| Alex     | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 3         | I don't know |
| Oliver   | 2           | Do you like ice cream? | 1         | Yes          |
| Bob      | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 2         | No           |
| Alex     | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 1         | Yes          | 
| Jack     | 3           | Do you like summer?    | 2         | No           |
| Bob      | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 3         | I don't know |
| Alex     | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 1         | Yes          |
| Oliver   | 4           | Do you like winter?    | 3         | I don't know |
```

For example, with next code I can find average of the answers for question 1 and 2 of each person who answered for these questions.

```
select
    employee,
    avg(
        case when question_id in (1, 2) then option_id else null end
    ) as average_score
from
    answers
group by
    employee
```

Result:

```
| EMPLOYEE | AVERAGE_SCORE |
|----------|---------------|
| Bob      | 2             |
| Alex     | 2,5           |
| Kate     | 3             |
| Oliver   | 1             |
```

Now, I want to know the number of users whose average of the answers for question 1 and 2 is >= than 2. I tried next code but it raise error:

```
select
    count(
        avg(
            case when question_id in (1, 2) then option_id else null end
        )
    ) as average_score
from
    answers
where
    average_score >= 2
group by
    answers.employee
```

ERROR:

```
SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot be nested
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter *after* aggregation.  That uses a `having` clause.  In Postgres, you can also use `filter`:

```
select employee,
       avg(option_id) filter (where question_id in (1, 2)) as average_score
from answers
group by employee
having avg(option_id) filter (where question_id in (1, 2)) > 2;
```

If you want the count, then use this as a subquery:  `select count(*) from <the above query>`.

It is strange that you are equating "option_id" with "score", but that is how your question is phrased.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right now I tested your code but it raise error: `column "average_score" does not exist`. Also can this be done without subquery for count?

Comment: Instead of `having average_score` I use full expression `avg(option_id) filter (where question_id in (1, 2))`.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use having clause.. it can be done simply as

```
select employee, [Average Score] = avg(case when question_id in (1, 2) 
                                            then option_id else null 
                                            end
                                       ) 
from answers group by employee having average_score > 2;
```

update :
It must work now...

```
select employee, average_score = avg(case when question_id in (1, 2) 
                                            then option_id else null 
                                            end
                                       ) 
from answers group by employee having average_score > 2;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `[Average Score]` expression is syntactically correct in PostgreSQL database. Right now I have syntax error at or near `[`.

Comment: Dont know why it is giving error in your context. However I have used it manytimes, It is working.